# Normal series and refinements

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

I am trying to show that no nontrivial refinements exists in the following series but haven't been able to make any progress:
$\{1\}\unlhd Z(SL_2(\mathbb{R}))\unlhd  SL_2(\mathbb{R})\unlhd Z(GL_2(\mathbb{R}))\unlhd GL_2(\mathbb{R})$ 
Is there a common technique of dealing with such kind of questions?

Comment: The first containment has index $2$, and the quotient of the second is the simple group ${\rm PSL}_2({\mathbb R})$. The third one is not a containment at all.

Comment: Perhaps you meant ${\rm SL}_2({\mathbb R}) \lhd Z({\rm GL}_2({\mathbb R})){\rm SL}_2({\mathbb R})$? But then the quotient group is isomorphic to ${\mathbb R}^\times/\langle -1 \rangle$, which is clearly not simple.